# Why do i get a runtime error in 'ideone' whereas the same code is working on other compilers like turbo C?

Tags: c++, c

**Question**:Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.
(Because of this i am not able to submit answer onto SPOJ)

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[5],i,j;
    printf("Enter some numbers:");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]==42)
        {
            j=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Removed extra language tags, this looks like pure C unless you are compiling it as C++ we should remove the C++ tag as well.

Comment: Your program doesn't fulfill this requirement: "Stop processing input after reading in the number 42". You only read in first 5 numbers the user entered, and the number 42 may not be among them.

Comment: You could have chosen newer "other compiler".

Comment: Hint: You can store just *one* number and still process arbitrarily many.

Comment: Please do not discuss on his algorithm. He is solving this problem on [online judge](http://spoj.com/?utm_campaign=permanent&utm_medium=view-right&utm_source=ideone).

Comment: BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.  In both C and C++.

Comment: Please be more specific on the errors that you see and what idea you would have that they could mean. Please also visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make sure that you know which programming language you are using. Seeing the whole list that you placed initially and the minimal effort that you put in formulating your question, I wonder if it was even you who wrote this.

Answer (score 3):

`j` has not been initialized where it is defined. It will continue to be uninitialized if you never enter the block that has the line

```
j = i;
```

Initialize `j` to `5` at the start of the program to avoid using an uninitialized value, which leads to undefined behavior.

You can also change the final loop to use `j` as the loop counter and `i` as the stopping value.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   if(a[i]==42)
   {
      ++i;
      break;
   }
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{
   printf("\n%d",a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*ideone* use GCC compiler to compile C programs. Your code have obsolete syntax which is valid only in obsolete compiler like Turbo C++ or older version of GCC.

Change `void main()` to `int main(void)` and it will work.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated?

Comment: Probably shouldn't have mocked Turbo C++ by calling it obsolete. It has feelings too, you know. Oh Wait. No it doesn't.

Comment: Even with the suggested change, code has UB as `j` may be used without first having a value assigned/initialized.